# Use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient as the nLog dbprovider

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I've upgraded an ASP.NET Core application from Entity Framework Core 2.x to 3.1. One consequence was to break nlog as it uses `System.Data.SqlClient` by default and EF Core 3+ uses `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, which lead to this error being emitted in the nLog internal log file:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

As `System.Data.SqlClient` is no longer being maintained and I believe is on the path to obsolescence (in my opinion, this is not Microsoft policy at the time of writing) I would like to configure nLog to use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` instead.

This documentation (https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Database-target#mysql-and-net-core) states that setting the db provider should do the trick. But it doesn't work. No errors within the nLog log file, but nothing is written to the database. What an I doing wrong?

This is the targets element from my nLog.config:

```
<targets async="true">
  <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />

  <target name="database" xsi:type="Database" dbProvider="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient">

    <connectionString>MyConnectionString</connectionString>
    <commandText>
      insert into dbo.Log (
      Application, Logged, Level, Message,
      Logger, Exception
      ) values (
      @Application, @Logged, @Level, @Message,
      @Logger, @Exception
      );
    </commandText>

    <parameter name="@application" layout="MyApplication" />
    <parameter name="@logged" layout="${date}" />
    <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
    <parameter name="@message" layout="url: ${aspnet-request-url} | action: ${aspnet-mvc-action} | ${message}" />

    <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
    <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:tostring}" />
  </target>
</targets>
```

Comment: You'll have to upgrade NLog or the relevant sink to a version that uses Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. EF Core 3 isn't exactly new.

Comment: It looks like [automatic loading of Microsoft.Data.SqlServer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/4087) was added in the NLog v5 which is in RC2 right now

Comment: NLog v5 only adds better support for guessing the DbProvider when none specified. If having explicitly specified the `dbProvider="..."` then NLog will use that. Maybe [activate the NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) and look for clues. Maybe the Logging-Rules are not configured correctly, or maybe the Microsoft LoggerFactory-filters are interfering. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Missing-trace%5Cdebug-logs-in-ASP.NET-Core-3%3F